# Create 1-D numpy array from image

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library, numpy-ndarray

edit: *copying from my comment to give more context to the problem*

> One important thing I forgot to mention is my end goal is to add this
>   as a column to a pandas dataframe. I was getting errors when trying to
>   put the pixels array as is into dataframe due to more than one
>   dimension.

I have a 32x32 image that I would like to flatten into a 1-D numpy array representing an object with the RGB values at that pixel.

```
img = Image.open(img_path)
pixels = np.asarray(img)
width, height = img.size
pixels = pixels.reshape(width * height, 3)
```

Currently this is the best I can do without losing the grouping of RGB values in one object. With this implementation however I get a 2-D array with each element being an array of the RGB values like this.

```
shape: (1024, 3)
[[255 255 255]
 [255 255 255]
 [255 255 255]
 ...
 [255 255 255]
 [255 255 255]
 [255 255 255]]
```

I would like my array to have shape `(1024,1)` and for each element to be some object (maybe a tuple?) of RGB values. Thanks.

Comment: That basically *is* what you have, but each (r,g,b) pixel is a numpy array, instead of a tuple. If you must have a tuple, then do `pixels = [tuple(x) for x in pixels]`. I'm not sure why you would want to do this though : you'll lose all the handy array-slicing capabilities of numpy. Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: One important thing I forgot to mention is my end goal is to add this as a column to a pandas dataframe. I was getting errors when trying to put the pixels array as is into dataframe due to more than one dimension.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c.f. comment, array as a dataframe or a series :

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(pixels)   # As a dataframe with one column per color channel
column = dataframe.apply(tuple, axis=1)  # As a Series of (r,g,b) tuples
```

Then you can use `column` as a column of another dataframe, if you so wish

Comment: Thank you! Why does `tuple` act as a function for the apply function?

Comment: In general, you can instantiate pythons built-in types either as *literals*, e.g.  `(1,2,3)`, which is interpreted as a tuple, or via *constructors*, e.g. `tuple(1,2,3)` where you make the type explicit. In your case, the `apply` method is taking every element and passing it as an argument to the `tuple` constructor. The equivalent (although unnecessary) version with a lambda function would be `dataframe.apply(lambda x: tuple(x))`, which makes the constructor at play more evident.